# How to effectively define a custom HTMLElement attribute in Javascript so as to be able to set it using HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

As an example (**please focus on the question**, not the example - I have good reasons for this), I'm trying to add a new 'placeholder' attribute on an HTMLSelectElement object in Javascript. So I go like this:

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" placeholder="Male">
    <option></option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    <option>Other</option>
</select>
```

Now if I run this, I get 'undefined':

```
var gender = document.getElementById('gender');
alert(gender['placeholder']);
```

So tried this approach to see if this would help:

`HTMLSelectElement.prototype.placeholder = '';`

But now I'm getting an empty string. Is there a simple way to access custom attributes on HTMLElements without having to loop through the HTMLElement.attributes one by one? Keep in mind I'm using Vanilla JS and some old browsers.

Comment: use `.placeholder` to set/get the placeholder `alert(gender.placeholder);`

Comment: A select does not have a placeholder... So what are that trying to solve?

Comment: @epascarello Exactly I'm trying to add a placeholder attribute to select elements.

Comment: @www139 That does not work some browsers (e.g. Chrome)

Comment: Thank you :) I wasn't aware of that (+1 on your question)

Comment: you can define `placeholder` as a getter/setter on `HTMLSelectElement.prototype`, which calls setAttribute/getAttribute internally, so that the attrib and property map eachother, like they do with  `title`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `getAttribute` to grab the placeholder value:
`document.getElementById("gender").getAttribute("placeholder")`

Comment: That was an easy one, I thought getAttribute was not supported by older browsers but it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

```
HTMLSelectElement.prototype.placeholder = '';
```

Actually set it to an empty string?

In your example, you need to set the Male option to Selected rather than using a placeholder which is applicable to text inputs.

Comment: Yes I know the prototype was not a good idea, but I'm using the placeholder for other reasons which would be too long to explain on this question.